# ASp.net site upload problems

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting

i have made a site in asp.net with backend as Access database , later i replaced it with mysql database,

The problem is i have uploaded my entire site on a host which provides the asp.net hosting and also the home page is coming perfectly fine, but when i click on any buttons on home page nothing seems to happen it is redirected to home page only,

Also when i access any other page except the home page, it gives run time error,

I have setup mysql database on  my host and also tried with sql server, but same results,
checked connection strings with the hosting provider but of no help,

can someone suggest me what is there i am missing at the time of upload.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: are you using any `DLL`..

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Provide more information about errors

Comment: You need to advise full error message or you can post your issue on forums.asp.net.

Comment: please elaborate issue and provide me the error which you are getting